# Iterating i to print file name

Tags: c

The jist of the code is that a user is prompted to input a max_x, max_y value, number of points and total files to create. From here a file is created, the code for what is inputted within the file works correctly.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

Assume the user inputs are:

Generating random instances ...

Enter the circuit board size MAX_X MAX_Y: 100 200

Enter the number of points NUM_PT: 10

Enter the number of random instances to be generated: 7

Where I am stuck is that the program won't iterate 7 times over and instead only creates 1 file with the name instance7_007.txt

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int max_x, max_y, num_pt, random_inst;
    int MAX_LEN = 200;
    int *x_coordinate, *y_coordinate;
    int inputfile = 0, outputfile = 0;
    int i;
    char name[MAX_LEN];

      if (argc == 1) {
        /* to generate random instances, accepting parameters from stdin */
        printf("Generating random instance . . .\n");
        printf("Enter the circuit board size MAX_X  MAX_Y: ");
        scanf("%d%d", &max_x, &max_y);
        printf("Enter the number of points NUM_PT: ");
        scanf("%d", &num_pt);
        printf("Enter the number of random instances to be generated: ");
        scanf("%d", &random_inst);
        for (i=1; i < random_inst; i++);
        {
          snprintf(name, MAX_LEN, "instance%d_%03d.txt", num_pt, i);
          fp = fopen(name, "w");
          printf("%s generated", &name);
          fprintf(fp, "#%s\n", argv[inputfile]);
          fprintf(fp, "area [0, MAX_X] x [0, MAX_Y]\n");
          fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", max_x, max_y);
          fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num_pt);
          fprintf(fp, "#coordinates\n");
          for (i=0; i < num_pt; i++)
          {
            fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", rand()%max_x, rand()%max_y);
          }
          fprintf(fp, "#end of instance\n");
          fclose(fp);
        }
        return 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: No compile errors come up either, so I am at a loss.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your program iterates only once is because you overwrite you looping variable in the inner loop. In both the outer and inner loop you use the same variable that has a scope of `main` - `i`. One fix is to add another looping variable (i.e. `int i, j` initially) and change the inner loop to:

```
for (j=0; j < num_pt; j++)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", rand()%max_x, rand()%max_y);
}
```

Alternatively you can reduce the scope of `i`s to their respective loops by declaring them in the loop statement,

```
for (int i=1; i < random_inst; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i=0; i < num_pt; i++)
```

This approach is actually useful and lets you avoid certain bugs.

Another problem is as @user501138 pointed out, your outer loop has an `;` which causes the loop body to be empty. Also, this line

`printf("%s generated", name);`

is incorrect in the original code as it has `&name` instead of `name` which represents a pointer to array of char arrays rather than a pointer to char array. I recommend you enable compiler warnings, as both of these things were pointed out by my compiler.

Finally, there is no need for `argc==1` check, at least not one obvious to me - `argc` will always be at least 1 - `argv` will always have one argument - the name of the program you're running. You can of course keep it there, with the above changes your program works as intended.

Comment: Thanks,  that was very helpful. Didn't know about the consequences with placing ; at the end of for.

Comment: Glad to help. Think of it this way - you know that you don't need braces after a loop statement, in which case the body of the loop is considered to be that one line/statement that follows it. In this case it's simply `;`, it actually counts as a statement. See the little addition of your loop variable alternative, it may prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon at the end of your for() loop statement.  Your loop is effectively not executing.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick, really confused with this one